# SQL How to select data that has all values above a value

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a Table called "MARKS" with the columns: Value, subject_id and student_id.
Now I want to write a query to display the names of all students who have secured more than 50 in ALL subjects that they have appeared in.
How can that be achieved?

Example:
Lets say the subjects are maths, english, history.
Even if a student scores 100 in maths, 100 in english but 40 in history, he should be considered as failed and not be displayed.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: Is it possible that a student has several scores in the same subject? Or will you have at most one mark (value) for each (student_id, subject_id) pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to get what you expect, but in the simplest case the `HAVING` clause may help. In the following query grouping is done by `student_id`, so the `min` function gets minimal value over all subjects for each `student_id`:

```
SELECT student_id
  FROM marks_table
 GROUP BY student_id
HAVING min(marks) > 50;
```

Then join student names by `student_id`.

Comment: sorry for not making my question clear, please see the edited version

Comment: @B Sumanth, so we just need to change `sum` to `min`. Check the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

Returns all students with subjects appeared

```
select  student_id,subject_id, value from marks
 where 
 (case when value < 50 then 'failed' else 'pass' end  ) = 'pass'
```

Comment: but if would display even if a student scored less than 50 in another subject. If he fails in even one subject, it should not be diplayed

Comment: It wont display any student id with less than <50 value

Comment: This answer is incorrect - if you have a student with 100 in Maths, 100 in English but 40 in History then this will display the results for that student in Maths and English when they should not be displayed at all (since History is less than 50).

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
 select student_id
 from table
 where student_id not in (
      select student_id 
      from table
      where value < 50
      )
```

Beware, if you have nulls in student_id you'll receive incorrect results. Geta round this with a coalesce() in the sub-select

Comment: @BSumanth This answer will require two table/index scans (one for the outer query and one for the sub-query) and will show duplicate rows for each student's subject - [using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44651134/1509264) will only require a single table scan and will only show unique values.

Comment: This will return each `student_id` several times though, right? As many times as they appear in the base table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
    (
        select student_id, MIN(Value) as sum_value
        from MARKS
        group by student_id
    ) summed
where
    sum_value > 50
```

Comment: Replace `SUM` with `MIN` and it will do what the OP is asking; but you could replace the outer query with the [`HAVING` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44651134/1509264)

Comment: it is true - after OP added an example it is more clearly what he wanted to achive.
I knot that this simple task could be achived with HAVING what was already mentioned, however this also. And in more complicated situation could be this more wanted solution. So i posted it just as an another opportunity...